# How to setup TypeScript, VScode, Yarn2, Fastify project

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, hadoop-yarn, fastify, yarn-v2

I know I've solved this before, but perhaps the landscape has changed since then.  I'm trying to setup a new project primarily using fastify, coding in VSCode in TypeScript and managing dependencies with Yarn2.

VSCode is telling me it cannot find fastify.  It also cannot find Node types despite adding both fastify and @types/node.  I've tried numerous permutations and steps of the following, insured I'm using the VSCode workspace version of TypeScript, revised the tsconfig.json to use node moduleResultion, etc.  Whatever used to work doesn't work anymore, but I haven't found a single other current post or bit of documentation that resolves the issue.

What am I missing?

```
nvm install node               ## Install latest NodeJS
node --version > .nvmrc        ## Set the node version to use
yarn init -y                   ## Project initialization
yarn set version berry         ## Use yarn v2
yarn add --dev typescript      ## TypeScript all the way
yarn add --dev ts-node         ## Easier Ts script or task execution
yarn plugin import typescript  ## Magic?
yarn add --dev @types/node     ## Node types
yarn add --dev @yarnpkg/pnpify ## Emulate ./node_modules
yarn pnpify --sdk vscode       ## Setup workspace/environment     
yarn tsc --init -t ES2020      ## Generate tsconfig.json
yarn add fastify               ## Add fastify dep
```

[image]

[image]

package.json

```
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@yarnpkg/pnpify": "^2.2.1",
    "ts-node": "^9.0.0",
    "typescript": "^4.0.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "fastify": "^3.4.1"
  }
}
```

Update: Despite answering VSCode's prompt to use the workspace version of TypeScript, I found that I still need to manually specify it via ctrl+shift+p > Select TypeScript version...  After doing that, the problem changes a bit.  Regardless of the import statement, I now see namespace issue:
[image]

Comment: try `import fastify from 'fastify`

Comment: In addition to what @ManuelSpigolon correctly pointed out. Don't forget to restart your IDE after you install packages if it doesn't pick them up. This happens. Also, your `tsconfig.json` is relevant to all of this. You can run `./node_modules/.bin/tsc --init` to get a good default `tsconfig` generated for you.

Comment: @AluanHaddad Yes, thank you.  I have noticed that as well and have been restarting VSCode.  I'm working with yarnv2 so I don't have a node_modules.  I strongly suspect, based on past experience, if I were to switch to NPM and the node_modules was created, these problems would go away, but I'm kind of set on using yarn 2.

Comment: You can configure it to work with that using typeRoots and paths. At least I assume so

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling trying to run fastify too.  It turn out that the problem is you have to run fastify with yarn node (your script name). Since the new yarn got rid of the node-module dir it can't find it. but yarn made a work around run there" yarn node" fix's this problem I don't know how this works though.